# Prevent .pdb files from being published to server- .NET 7 and Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net-7.0

I want to remove the .pdb files on Release so they don't go to the server after publish. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and .NET 7.

I've tried absolutely everything I've read and it still doesn't work. I tried changing Debug Symbols to No Symbols are emitted through properties. I tried putting settings in .pubxml and .csproj

Comment: Did you set `<DebugType>None</DebugType>`  as well?

Comment: Yes I try to set in .pubxml

Comment: I've heard that apparently you're able to delete .PDB file, and it apparently won't corrupt the application, apart from returning less debugging information, for example, during the throw statement. You can attempt to *rename* the PDB file first. If the application does not start with PDB file not being found, you can try to rename it back. Ensure the application is really set on **Release** instead of **Debug** in Visual Studio.